# Angular - ngClass being added to each clicked radio button (instead of ONLY clicked one)

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

In my `angular` app I'm using `ng-repeat` to generate several `radio` buttons, the ultimate goal is to add a `choiceSelected` class (`ngClass` colour styling) to the `label` of the clicked `radio` input. I can add the style to the clicked button, BUT that style is added to every other clicked `radio` button and I end up with 5 coloured labels. Can't understand why.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in questionObject.choices">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="choice" ng-class="{'choiceSelected': isChecked==$index}">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="isChecked" ng-value="$index" ng-click="selectAnswer($index,questionObject)">{{obj.body}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does your **selectAnswer** function is doing?

Comment: Nothing that matters. Just passes some data and prints it to console.

Comment: your questionObject json?

Comment: Yes it is. I get the data, everything works as expected except for the `ngClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in questionObject.choices">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="choice" ng-class="{'choiceSelected': isChecked==$index}">
         <input type="radio"
          name="optradio"
           /*********************************************/
           ng-model="isChecked"
           ng-value="$index"
           /*********************************************/
           ng-click="selectAnswer($index,questionObject)">{{obj.body}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Look at the lines inside the comments, clearly tells that your value of the checkbox(**$index**) is binding to the **isChecked** variable.

By your, **condition**  in ng-class **isChecked==$index** it is same for all the elements and so the class is applied for all radio buttons.

if you can update the Json of **questionObject** , can give you alternative option.

Assuming that questionObject  contains the following json

```
 [{
    "body": "abc"
  }, {
    "body": "def"
  }, {
    "body": "aghi"
  } ]
```

You can use the below code to make your result achieve

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in questionObject track by $index" >
    <div class="radio" >
        <label class="choice" 
        ng-class="{'choiceSelected': isChecked==$index}">
          <input type="radio"
         name="optradio"
         ng-value="obj.body"
         ng-click="selectAnswer($index,obj)">
         {{obj.body}}
         </label>
</div>
```

The method **selectAnswer** should make your work simple. Use this

```
 $scope.selectAnswer=function(number,obj)
  {
    $scope.isChecked=number;
  }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NqrKk4liTIPyx90YloTe?p=preview)

> NOTE: In your code the **selectAnswer** method call in HTML passes the
>   questionObject fully

Update 1

Reason for manually defining isChecked

Angular looks for the the value of **isChecked** in the scope because you have used **ng-class** in the

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot modify the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Can you explain why you had to manually define `isChecked`?

Comment: `isChecked` has to be defined on the parent scope otherwise it would not toggle on changing between radios of the same name.
If you don't want to use `selectAnswer()` you can use `ng-click=$parent.isChecked=$index`